How to add a docx file to a session in flask
I cannot add my docx file to my flask session, when I try and access the file later on there is nothing in the session.
document = Document('mydocument.docx')
session['documentsession'] = document

Later on:
documentaccessed = session.get('documentsession')

Running the document through using BytesIO

I'm not sure that storing a possibly several megabytes file in session is the best way to achieve what you need. This might be an X/Y problem. Suggestion: edit your question explaining what you want to achieve
